# ASP.Core ODataControllers not recognizing "get by key" operation

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm investigating how to use OData in ASP.Core.

I've created a `BooksController`, subclassed from `ODataController`, within which I've defined two Actions:  `Get()`, and `Get(int id)`.

`/odata/books` resolves to the first Action, but `/odata/books(1)` does not find the second Action.

Once the Models are defined, it is able to find the following Controller:

```cs
[ODataRoutePrefix("Books")]
public class BooksController : ODataController
{
    private BookStoreContext _db;

    public BooksController(BookStoreContext context)
    {
        _db = context;
    }

    [ODataRoute]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(_db.Books);
    }

    [EnableQuery]
    [ODataRoute("({key})")]
    public IActionResult Get([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        return Ok(_db.Books.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == key.ToGuid()));
    }
}
```

The site has the default Convention rules for all routes (see below). 
But I think this is not in play, as the `BooksController` is decorated with `[ODataRoutePrefix("Books")]` and the actions with `[ODataRoute]` (and `[EnableQuery]`) -- which I think, being Attribute based routing, take precedence (is that a correct assumption?).

My dto models are are registered using Reflection...), but the key part is where Startup invokes `UseMvc(...)`, and defines the routes, which ends up calling here:

```cs
private void CreateODataRoutes(IRouteBuilder routeBuilder)
{
    // register the convention routes for MVC first...
            routeBuilder.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    ...

    // then do the OData stuff...

    routeBuilder.Count().Expand().Filter()
        .MaxTop(100).OrderBy().Select();

    // Use method further down the page 
    // to create a Build Model by reflection, using
    // all OData Model definitions (ie, classes that implement
    // IAllModulesOdataModelBuilderConfiguration)
    var oDataConventionModelBuilder = BuildODataModelUsingReflectionAcrossAllAssemblies();

    // Use the modelBuilder as the basis of defining routes:
    RegisterRoutesToODataController(routeBuilder, oDataConventionModelBuilder);
}
```

Where `BuildODataModelUsingReflectionAcrossAllAssemblies` uses reflection to find individual model definitions, each one pretty simple, only defining their id (relying on convention for the rest).

Note that I'm not defining Actions as that used to be by convention (see further down).

```cs
    public class BookODataModelBuilderConfigurationBase<T> : IAllModulesOdataModelBuilderConfiguration
        where T : class, IHasGuidId, new()
    {

        public virtual void Apply(ODataModelBuilder builder ...) 
        {
            var _controllerName = this.GetControllerNameByConvention(typeof(Book));
            var entity = builder.EntitySet<T>(this._controllerName).EntityType;
            entity.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        //Note...no Actions defined, as planning to rely on default conventions (routing by Verb to method starting with Get...)
        }
    }
```

When the model is created, it is registered as follows;

```cs
        private void RegisterRoutesToODataController(IRouteBuilder routeBuilder,
            ODataConventionModelBuilder oDataConventionModelBuilder)
        {
            string routePrefix = $"{App.Modules.Core.Shared.Constants.ModuleSpecific.Module.AssemblyNamePrefix}.";

            // Build the Edm model used to parse commands:
            var edmModel = oDataConventionModelBuilder.GetEdmModel();

            // Register the Odata paths
            routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute(
                routeName: $"{routePrefix}odataDefault",
                routePrefix: "odata",
                edmModel,
                pathHandler:new DefaultODataPathHandler(),
                // By convention? So that Get verb goes to Get action, etc.
                routingConventions: ODataRoutingConventions.CreateDefault()
            );
        }
```

When the path is `/odata/book(1)` it returns `HTTP ERROR 404`, the page does not exist.

Thank you!

Other things I've tried include:

- commented out configuration of SwaggerAPI
- Removed `[FromODataUri]` on the key param (is it necessary?)
- Added/removed `[ODataRoute("({key})")]`
- Registered the Controller as `BooksController` in plural/singular
- Changed the name of the Action to `GetBook` and back again to `Get`
- Added/removed `ODataRoutePrefix`
- registering the OData routes before registering the default convention routes (think that should be the case all the time, right?).
- ...all of which is starting to look more like desperation than coding :-( ...
- Still looking. Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: In the controller attribute `[ODataRoutePrefix("Books")]` you specify 'Books' with a captital letter. But your test url is `/odata/books(1)` with a small 'b'. Could you test to see if this is the issue?

Comment: Thanks GWigWag. It's case insensitive. Both work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG. (sheepishly) solved.
It wasn't the Framework, Nuget, the Controller base class, routeprefix, routes, or anything glorious, it was ...me. 
The only place I was not looking was the Model itself, which defined the Id as a Guid. The Action was using an int, converting it to a Guid. 
ASP.Core could not find it because it was building routes based on the Model (not the Controller), so ignored the Action as it made no sense to its convention based route building as an int != Guid. duh.

If you were wondering why the heck I used an int...it was because when I had seeded the Db I wanted a Guid Key, but for testing purposes I wanted some records to have specific Ids that I could refer back to, and I was lazy, and didn't want to type in a full Guid.

That was a DUMB idea, in retrospect...:-(

But thank you for looking into it! Appreciate the time spent.

Comment: Good to hear you found the issue. You should probably mark this answer as the 'accepted answer'.